# I cant install realm in react-native?what could be the reason?

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm, cross-platform

I am new to this..is there anyone can help me to figure out this error?

I tried to install Realm in my React-Native project,unfortunately it didnt went well, I couldnt understand what is the problem..is there anyone can help me to figure out the error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question doesn't really provide enough information for any to help. We don't know what *this error* refers to, what steps you took to install it or even you coding environment.  The [Realm React Native Installation Guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/install/) is pretty well tested at this point so going through that may resolve the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.